# Select a string within a string within ATHENA

Tags: sql, string, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a table in AWS ATHENA that I need to clean up for production, but having difficulties extracting only a specfic portion of a string.

**EXAMPLE:**

| Column A |
| --- |
| {"display_value":"TECH_FinOps_SERVICE","link":" [https://sdfs.saff-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sys_user_group/8fc10b99dbeedf12321317e15b9619b2"}](https://sdfs.saff-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sys_user_group/8fc10b99dbeedf12321317e15b9619b2%22%7D) |

Basically I would like to just extract Tech_FinOps_Service from the string in Column_A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string looks like json so you can try using [json functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(column_a) AS (
    values ('{"display_value":"TECH_FinOps_SERVICE","link":" https://sdfs.saff-now.com/api/now/v2/table/sys_user_group/8fc10b99dbeedf12321317e15b9619b2"}')
)

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(column_a, '$.display_value') display_value
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
    display_value    
---------------------
 TECH_FinOps_SERVICE
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much for the quick response and help.